# Is Amazon provide any scheduler Api for scheduling the email

Tags: amazon-ses, amazon-sns

I'm using Amazon SES/SNS API of Amazon for sending email and getting notification.
Is Amazon provide any scheduler Api for scheduling the email for future? As i want to schedule my email by using Amazon API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SES does not provide this functionality. You would need to do that yourself using a task scheduler such as the built-in windows or perhaps quartz.net if you need something more sophisticated

Answer (score 0):

While they may not offer it directly in SES or SNS, they do offer similar functionality with SQS or SWF.

Answer (score 0):

I made the service, [huhumails.com](https://www.huhumails.com)

With [HuhuMails](https://www.huhumails.com), you can schedule your transactional emails with ease. It also makes sure emails are sent within your rate-limits. The service accepts date and timezone parameters to schedule your email at a specific time in the future.

I couldn't find anything on the market that's according to what I'm looking for and easy to use, so I created the service. I'm currently using it on my other production websites. Hopefully, it will be useful to others too.